# NoResultException No entity found for query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, null

please I can't find where is the problem with my query it always show me null even if I pass manually the string that match with login stored in DB, when I change "=" with "like" it works fine, the problem with like it return all rows starting with the string I don't know what's wrong, this is my code thanks and sorry for my english.

```
public Utilisateur getUserByLogin(String login) {
    Query req=em.createQuery("select u from Utilisateur u where u.login  =:login ");
    req.setParameter("login", "%"+login+"%");
    Utilisateur u = null;
    try{
         u = (Utilisateur)req.getSingleResult();
                }
        catch (NoResultException nre){

        }

        if(u == null){
         return null;
        }else{
            return u;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
    req.setParameter("login", login);
```